# How to pass the list of parameters with TYPE VARRAY of VARCHAR2 to the PL-SQL stored procedure and access list of parameters in loop

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, parameter-passing, oracle-sqldeveloper, varray

I want to send parameter list with TYPE VARRY of VARCHAR2 to a stored procedure in oracle and access each parameter in loop.

Any help will be wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: The Oracle PL/SQL documentation is a marvellous thing. I suspect you bookmark it, as you can easily answer questions like this by studying the examples. For instance, [here is the second on VARRAY collections](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-E932FC04-C7AD-4562-9555-8BA05446C0B8).

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. This question is way too broad, edit it so that it has specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Thenk you for your inputs. :)